# How can i connect multipule html pages using same sessionid in socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, socket.io

I have the following client scripts

One is my is a function that sits on my index.html

```
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('https://private.c9.io/');
socket.emit('Start', 'tobi', function (data) {
var sessionid = socket.socket.sessionid;
    console.log(data + " " + sessionid); // data will be 'sessionid'
});
</script>
```

and the other is a function that sits on my page2.html

```
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect("https://private.c9.io/");  //i need to set session id from index.html
    socket.emit('Start2', 'tobi', function (data) {
    console.log(data); // data will be 'result'
});


</script>
```

Problem is when I use socket connect on each page the sessionid is diffrent and I need 
the sessionid of socket.io to be the same for both.

I just need help on how I can set my session id on the page2.html function.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can't re-use the session ID, and nor would you want to.  Simply pass some sort of token to both pages and use that when your clients connect to Socket.IO so that your server can show that the client is the same.

Comment: @Brad could you show me an example or point me in the right direction

Comment: @Brad is right. You can use rooms here. Use some kind of token and make the pages join a same room if the token sent from them is same.