# Use same socket, although sites change

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io for a website and I establish the socket connection within my index.html and my script.js

At the end of script.js I call

```
window.location = "main.html"
```

Is it possible to keep the same socket connection I had in index.html on main.html?

Comment: Which backend language used in project??

Comment: I use nodejs as backend

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single page application that have no reload between in pages ,in that case socket connection exist so that no change in socket connection.

And if it reload then put the below code on Node JS ,and it re-initialization the socket connection that first time disconnect socket then again connect and save the all connected socket details in `clients` variable:

```
var clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('add-user', function(data) {
        clients[data.user_id] = {
            "socket": socket.id
        };
    });

    //Removing the socket on disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        for (var name in clients) {
            if (clients[name].socket === socket.id) {
                delete clients[name];
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am loading another page, but I want to be able to address the same client (therefore the same socket.id) although he switches to the other page.

Comment: I share my one of my github project and check how i do,hope it will help you how i do https://github.com/zahid492/Realtime-colloboration-App-MEAN-Socket.io/blob/master/server.js

Comment: It's can not possible to store a single socket ID ,if you visit multiple page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920941/how-can-i-connect-multipule-html-pages-using-same-sessionid-in-socket-io?rq=1